# I want to constrain my textbox to persian alphabet, how can I do it? In C#

Tags: c#, textbox

I want a textbox to accept just Persian alphabet, and don't accept any signs in C#. Can anyone help me with code?

Comment: Please add some code, do you want to restrict input in the frontend view via JS/Jquery? What setup are you using?

Comment: What kind of textbox? WinForms? ASP.NET? WPF? What do you mean by "don't get any signs"? What have you tried so far?

Comment: normal textbox in winform in c# ,signs like : &^%$#

Answer (score 3):

This is probably what you're looking for:

```
// Only allows "Persian characters" and "Space".
private void TextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!Regex.IsMatch(e.KeyChar.ToString(), @"\p{IsArabic}")
        && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar.ToString()))
        e.Handled = true;
}

// Only allows "Persian characters", "Space" and "Numbers".
private void TextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!Regex.IsMatch(e.KeyChar.ToString(), @"\p{IsArabic}")
        && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar.ToString())
        && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

Specific character sets in the Unicode standard occupy a specific range or block of consecutive code points. For example, the basic Latin character set is found from `\u0000` through `\u007F`, while the Arabic character set is found from `\u0600` through `\u06FF`.
The regular expression construct

```
\p{ name }
```

matches any character that belongs to a Unicode general category or named block.

You can read more about Unicode Block [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#CategoryOrBlock).

Comment: This is True. But you need to define the event for textbox too. otherwise this method remains useless. +1 for Regex and `"\p{IsArabic}"`

Comment: (Regex) A regular expression is a pattern that could be matched against an input text. [source](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_regular_expressions.htm)... Regex is used to compare string with algorithm. for example `Regex("[0-9]")` means only strings that contains numbers between 0 and 9 are accepted in comparison. there are many topics about Regex. you can search in google. @FatemehHojjati

Comment: @FatemehHojjati use `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex` or add `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` to access `Regex` class and read "M.kazem Akhgary" comment to learn more on this subject.

Comment: this code Freeze textbox and user can not delete nothing

Answer (score 1):

You must add event for your textbox. What you want is KeyPress Event.

see this tutorial in DotNet Perls.

> [C# TextBox Tutorial: TextChanged and KeyDown](http://www.dotnetperls.com/textbox)

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = !e.KeyChar <= 'BiggestPersianChar' && !e.KeyChar >= 'SmallesPersianChar';
}
```

Currently i dont know the Biggest persian char and smallest one. but i hope you know it.

Edit:

I Guess that these are biggest and smallest char. by Big and small i mean its Unicode.

```
e.Handled = !e.KeyChar <= 'ی' && !e.KeyChar >= 'ا';
```

Comment: don't matter big or small,just be persian

Comment: i know. each Character has `ascii` Code. Forexample ascii code of `A` is `65`. when you press key on your keyboard you must check that if that char is in range of persian Alphabet or not. so you will say `e.KeyChar <= ی` and `e.KeyChar >= 'ا'`. means `e.KeyChar`(The key that you have pressed) should be between ی and ا and does not accept any other word or sign. But to do this you must define this event for textbox. see the tutorial @FatemehHojjati

Comment: sorry. Persian chars does not have ascii code. they have Unicode. see Bahman_Aries answer. however this solution still remains true! @FatemehHojjati